# Which architecture pattern is suitable for Xamarin android development?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm new in Xamarin development. can you suggest which architecture pattern use for development. just like MVVM,MVP,MVC, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will now go with MVP considering the asynchronous nature of mobile applications. Check a discussion here https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/01/17/xamarin-application-architecture/

Comment: yeah its good. will be more helpful if you can provide a sample for MVP in xamarin.Android the above blog is for xamarin.Ios project

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms was designed with MVVM in mind. As for the Platform specific MVVM or passive view both work well.